# GraphQL result for another mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo, graphql-mutation

Is it meanwhile possible to use the result of a GraphQL mutation as a parameter for another mutation?

I would like to create a user and his address together in one call.

First I write the address and then take the address id for the creation of the user.
Filling the necessary data via the inputs works perfectly

Is this possible without triggering a new mutation from the client?

```
const createUser = gql`
  mutation createUser(
    $user: createUserInput!
    $address: createAddressInput!
  ) {
    createAddress(input: $address) {
      address {
        id       
      }
    }
    createUser(input: $user ) {
      user {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: You would need to add a third mutation that does both operations together. Calling two mutations, one after another implies two calls from the client.

Comment: you are right about the two calls, but is it possible to get the address id directly in the createUser call?

Comment: Not directly. Since we're talking of two calls they're are independent. The client must supply the parameter, even if it comes as the output of a previous mutation. If keeping the same schema, it's client responsability. If you add another, "two-in-one" mutation, then the server can know to forward the data internally.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. You either have to make two sequential requests from the client, or adapt your server implementation. I recommend the latter.

You should change your schema so that the `CreateUserInput` type to not only accepts an `addressId: ID` but alternatively can accept a `newAddress: CreateAddressInput` object, which it will then use to create a new address before creating a new user.